# How can I use an alias in a calculated expressions?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

Access SQL statements to MSSQL. I am having problems with using aliases within a calculated expression. Here is an example:

```
CASE WHEN AFACL.KGCOMPTI = 0 THEN 0 ELSE AFACL.VARGLINV END AS FaInventory, 
CASE WHEN AFACL.KGCOMPTA = 0 THEN 0 ELSE AFACL.AMOUNT END AS FaPurch, 
CASE WHEN AFACL.KGCOMPTM = 0 THEN 0 ELSE AFACL.VARGLINV * - 1 END AS FaVariance, 
CASE WHEN AFACL.CDTAX = 2  THEN 0 ELSE ROUND((AFACL.MTLIGNE * GTAXL.T2RATE1 / 100), 2) END  AS TaxAmount2,
CASE WHEN AFACL.CDTAX = 3 THEN 0 ELSE ROUND((AFACL.MTLIGNE * GTAXL.T1RATE1 / 100), 2) END AS TaxAmount1 ,  
[FaInventory]+[FaPurch]+[FaVariance]+[TaxAmount2]+[TaxAmount1] AS [Payable]
```

The last line does not work. Can anybody out there help me out with this? I do not know any MSSQL, as I usually work with MS-Access. Thank you in advance

Comment: You can introduce an *outer* select, in which case the column names introduced (by the now-nested select) can be used. The query planner will push everything through correctly - as long as view operations happen at the outer select, anyway - so there is no performance issue.

Comment: (But please *do* include the actual error message, I imagine it will be like: "Invalid column name '..'")